# R: How to create a function with if-statements to search for a file in multiple paths

Tags: r, function, if-statement

The code below is what I usually use in Python. Now I want to do this in R, but I can't find an example of the documentation of if statements in a def. Is this even possible?

```
def loadfile():
    if 'test.csv' in os.listdir():
        return 'test.csv'
    elif os.path.exists('../../project1/data/'):
        return '../../project1/data/test.csv'
    elif os.path.exists('../../../project1/data/'):
        return '../../../project1/data/test.csv'
```

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [file.exists](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/files) and [dir.exists](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/logcondens.mode/versions/1.0.1/topics/dir.exists) for your checks.

For the `if` statements, you need parentheses around the Boolean clause and curly braces for the body. You do not need to specify a `return(value)` directly, because R will automatically return the last variable evaluated in a function.

Bringing it together:

```r
loadfile <- function() {
  if (file.exists('test.csv')) {
    'test.csv'
  } else if (dir.exists('../../project1/data')) {
    '../../project1/data/test.csv'
  } else if (dir.exists('../../../project1/data')) {
    '../../../project1/data/test.csv'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If statements are build like following example in R:

```
if (condition) {
   statement
} else if (condition) {
 ...
} else {
 ... 
}
```